# How to quickly calculate the average of multiple columns in DolphinDB?

Tags: pandas, slice, dolphindb

Suppose there is a table as shown in the following figure:

I want to calculate the average of all columns, excluding “tradetime“. `avg(data)` is infeasible since it includes "tradetime". In DolphinDB, how to select a specified range of data, as `df.iloc[1:]` in pandas, and calculate the average of each column?

How to set "tradetime" as the index of the table, as `df.set_index('tradetime')` in pandas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaprogramming to generate the following SQL statement:

```
sql(sqlCol(["col1", "col2", "col3"], avg), t)
```

`["col1", "col2", "col3"]` can be replaced with `t.colNames()` to access the column(s) excluded for calculation. If all columns for calculations are of numeric type, you can also convert the table to a matrix and calculate the average of specified columns as follows:

```
matrix(t.values()[1:]).rename!(t.values()[0],)
avg(t)
```